# Batch file to open 4 or 6 internet explorer screens and place them by dividing the desktop equally

Tags: windows, script, batch, internet-explorer, automation

I intend to write a script that can open 4-6 IE screens that can be automatically be placed on the desktop.

So essentially all of them will get equal space on the desktop. I am aware of the command to open 4 or more IE screens however i am not able to place them on different part of the desktop using the script. Below is the example of the script that i am using to open the IE screens.

```
@echo off

start /d "" IEXPLORE.EXE 172.21.83.51
start /d "" IEXPLORE.EXE 172.21.83.52
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Windows batch has no native command to move/resize a window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977322/set-the-window-position-of-an-application-via-command-line). You would need additional helper tools as listed in the SO question

Answer (score 2):

#### Batch can't do this. But PowerShell can

Here is a very simple example to open two Internet Explorer windows and move/resize them

```
$ie1 = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie1.navigate("http://google.com")
$ie1.visible = $true    
$ie1.top = 10
$ie1.width = 790
$ie1.height = 790 
$ie1.Left = 10
  
$ie2 = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie2.navigate("http://bing.com")
$ie2.visible = $true    
$ie2.top = 10
$ie2.width = 790
$ie2.height = 790 
$ie2.Left = $ie1.Left + $ie2.width
```